# Disk is likely to fail soon (37° C / 99° F)

Tags: disk, smart

Almost a fresh install of Ubuntu 3 days old. I never had a single problem with running Windows 10 on this laptop for the last 3 years. I don't know what happened.

[image]

What should I do to diagnose this?

[image: First]

[image: Second]

[image]

I am completely new at using a Linux-based OS.
I have been using Windows for years. Now I mainly switched to Linux on my laptop for privacy issues, evading data collecting the most I can. I use a computer for video edition, webmastering and social medias. I have a chef brand.

When I want to import my data from a USB external HDD and/or SD card reader I get a `Read error on swap-device` error.

I don't really want to go back on Windows for explanation on top, but since I don't know commands and coding I need a little help here.

`~$ free -h`:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.6Gi       4.4Gi       274Mi       801Mi       2.9Gi       2.1Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi       118Mi       1.9Gi
```

`~$ grep -i swap /etc/fstab`:

```
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

`~$ sudo blkid`:

```
  asdasd/dev/sda2: UUID="04df9e3d-3c3c-4a1b-8177-961c7fa8dc41" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="0e9d6cbf-f602-4f5f-a6ff-cbf6a3f1cb47"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: UUID="06C2-BFC1" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="8063f3cf-da82-4d74-81d1-1fbc716caef1"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop13: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop14: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop15: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop16: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop17: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop18: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop19: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop20: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop21: TYPE="squashfs"
```

Added picture:

[image: gnome disks says DISK IS LIKELY TO FAIL SOON]

Comment: Are you asking about Read error or Video Editing ?

Comment: @SorenA Let's stick with the `Read error on swap-device` error here, and save the other distro recommendation and video editing questions for another question.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and `sudo blkid`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema here it is edited

Comment: Don't see any problem yet... show me screenshot(s) of the `Disks` app SMART Data (scrollable) window.

Comment: note: it has nothing to do with the temps, just that your SMART tests indicate your disk is in the process of dying.

Comment: Make backups on another disk.  If you don't have another disk, limit use of laptop till you get one.  Buy replacement disk for laptop.  Once backups and replacement disk done, can use old disk till it dies, then replace.

Comment: I understand what you guys are telling me but do you guys think its a coincidence that it shows this, that it was the time of the hard drive die, because like i said, it never said anything about this for 3 years on windows i never had issue.

Comment: @heynnema see the link in the post, thank you for your help! It tells me disk is gonna die soon, tho i am sure it is because of all the BOSD i had showing me error of swap and stuff, i did hard resets on the laptop when it happened, what should i do next

Comment: Yes, it is a coincidence. Coincidences happen every day. A fresh install is time you are most likely to glance at your disk condition. You said it yourself: The disk is at least three years old. Most of my disks last longer, too...but failure after three years does happen. Rarely, but does happen.

Comment: You have to press <Ctrl>+<S> inside the GNOME Disks to show *SMART Data & Self-test*. Please add this screenshot to the question in full size, without scroll.

Comment: Buy a new disk. Backup your files before the disk dies. Install new disk. Restore backed up data.

Comment: To actually see the SMART Data, you have to click on the "hamburger" icon and select it there. It's a scrollable window, so it may take 2 screenshots to get it all. Let me know when you have it for me to review.

Comment: @monsieurchefpatron `sudo smartctl -t short /dev/sda` ... (wait) ... `sudo smartctl -t long /dev/sda` ... (wait) ... `sudo smartctl -x /dev/sda`

Comment: Please see my comments in your other question regarding this subject. Please don't ask the same question twice.

Comment: 3-5 years is the expected lifespan of a HDD although they do often hold out for longer, sometimes much longer. Both HDDs and SSDs are considered "consumable". Dead at 3 years is pretty unfortunate, but it does happen.  Disk failure over time looks like a ["bathtub curve"](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Bathtub_curve), so you're unlucky that it failed in the midrange, but not so unlucky that it didn't die immediately after return/warranty period.

Comment: @heynnema edited ! :) thank you for your support everybody

Comment: It looks like the disk is failing... but for fun... let's check one more thing... edit your question and show me `grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog*`

Comment: @heynnema the command line did not work?

Comment: Didn't work or gave an error, or didn't report any hits? If no hits, then replace the drive.

Comment: @heynnema can you see the last screenshot? :)

Comment: Yes, I can see it. Replace the drive.

Comment: I had similar SMART data indication that disk is failing. See here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/789051/what-does-end-to-end-disk-error-mean

Comment: is it easy to replace the drive from a laptop, i never opened a laptop before, only PC towers

Answer (score 6):

Those SMART errors mean that disk failure is imminent.  You will need to replace the disk soon.

If you don't have sufficient backups, make them now before it's too late.

Comment: Until we see actual SMART Data, and check /var/log/syslog for FPDMA NCQ errors, or bad block errors, it's too early to confirm a disk failure. OP hasn't responded with that data yet... in their original question about this.

Comment: @hey "Assessment" is a summary of the SMART data. If it says "DISK IS LIKELY TO FAIL SOON", we really don't need to wait for the details